# Importing JavaScript file into Swift file

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I am trying to execute a JavaScript SDK from within a Swift application. I am unable to find the file however. I added the file to the project using cmd + click project -> Add files to "projectName" -> Add file and move into projectName/ folder.

I am still unable to get the file and run it inside a `JSContext`.

Where am I going wrong?

Here is my code (`isOK` is just used for a test case):

```
import Foundation
import JavaScriptCore

public class Wrapper {
    public var isOK: Bool
    var jsContext: JSContext

    init (pathToSdk: String) {
        let virtualMachine = JSVirtualMachine()
        self.jsContext = JSContext(virtualMachine: virtualMachine)

        if let sdkBundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: pathToSdk, ofType: "js") {
            let bundleString = try! String(contentsOfFile: sdkBundle)
            self.jsContext.evaluateScript(bundleString)
            print("Successfully initialised JavaScript context")
            self.isOK = true
        } else {
            print("Unable to fetch SDK bundle at path: \(pathToSdk)")
            self.isOK = false
        }
    }
}
```

I call it in my test:

```
func testIsOK() {
    let wrapper = Wrapper(pathToSdk: "sdk").isOK
    XCTAssertEqual(wrapper, true)
}
```

And my folder structure:
[image: Folder structure]

Thanks and sorry if this is a silly question, I'm brand new to Swift.